# PHP SMTP mail function not working with phpmailer

Tags: php, smtp

PHP SMTP mail function not working with phpmailer and throwing following error

> **Error:** SMTP Error: Language string failed to load: tls.

My Code is :

```
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');

$mail  = new PHPMailer();   
$mail->IsSMTP();    
$mail->SMTPAuth   = True;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                 // sets the prefix to the server
$mail->Host       = "localhost";      
$mail->Port       = 25;                 
$mail->Username   = "xxxxxx@xxxxx.org.in";  // my username
$mail->Password   = "xxxx";            // my password

$mail->From       = "xxxxxxx@xxxxx.org.in";
$mail->FromName   = "you name";
$mail->Subject    = "some subject";
$mail->MsgHTML("the message");

$mail->AddAddress("yyyyyy@gmail.com","logan");
$mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML

if(!$mail->Send()) {//to see if we return a message or a value bolean
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else  echo "Message sent!";
```

I have got the host and port details my web service provider but not working.

When i debug, following is the error:

```
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, and/or bulk e-mail.
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-mail02.clientns.net [127.0.0.1], this server offers 4 extensions 250-AUTH LOGIN 250-SIZE 52428800 250-HELP 250 AUTH=LOGIN
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:503 Bad sequence of commands
SMTP -> ERROR: STARTTLS not accepted from server: 503 Bad sequence of commands
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 Requested mail action okay, completed
Language string failed to load: tls Mailer Error: Language string failed to load: tls
```

Could any one please let me know why is it not connecting ?

Comment: `I have got the host and port details my web service provider` so why are you using localhost?

Comment: @dev-null-dweller: they said to use localhost

Comment: with ssl on port 25? I have hard time believing that.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller : then what should be there in place of ssl ? localhost and 25 are given by service provider

Comment: nothing. there is no point on securing connection to localhost. Just like there is no point in providing username and password while setting `SMTPAuth` to false. Have you tried reading the manual or examples to phpmailer?

Comment: @dev-null-dweller: when is use SMTPSecure = "tsl"; it says
Mailer Error: Language string failed to load: tls

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22670/discussion-between-logan-and-dev-null-dweller)

Comment: @dev-null-dweller : when i debug : it says
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, and/or bulk e-mail.
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-mail02.clientns.net [127.0.0.1], this server offers 4 extensions 250-AUTH LOGIN 250-SIZE 52428800 250-HELP 250 AUTH=LOGIN
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:503 Bad sequence of commands
SMTP -> ERROR: STARTTLS not accepted from server: 503 Bad sequence of commands
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 Requested mail action okay, completed
Language string failed to load: tls Mailer Error: Language string failed to load: tls

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It worked for me when i remove following..

```
//$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
```

Answer (score 1):

You tell PHPMailler to use a secured mail service hosted on your server.
If you don't know if it's the case, comment the lines as this and test it (it will use php native "mail()" function as described [here](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=exampleamail)):

```
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');

$mail  = new PHPMailer();   
//$mail->IsSMTP();    
//$mail->SMTPAuth   = false;                  // enable SMTP authentication
//$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 // sets the prefix to the server
//$mail->Host       = "localhost";      
//$mail->Port       = 25;                 
//$mail->Username   = "xxxxxx@xxxxx.org.in";  // my username
//$mail->Password   = "xxxx";            // my password

$mail->From       = "xxxxxxx@xxxxx.org.in";
$mail->FromName   = "you name";
$mail->Subject    = "some subject";
$mail->MsgHTML("the message");

$mail->AddAddress("yyyyyy@gmail.com","logan");
$mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML

if(!$mail->Send()) {//to see if we return a message or a value bolean
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else  echo "Message sent!";
```

Comment: i have got error like,
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, and/or bulk e-mail.
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-mail02.clientns.net [127.0.0.1], this server offers 4 extensions 250-AUTH LOGIN 250-SIZE 52428800 250-HELP 250 AUTH=LOGIN
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:503 Bad sequence of commands
SMTP -> ERROR: STARTTLS not accepted from server: 503 Bad sequence of commands
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 Requested mail action okay, completed
Language string failed to load: tls Mailer Error: Language string failed to load: tls

Comment: And if you comment:
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; 
?

Comment: if i comment that , it says Not authenticated & you can not send mail to outside; says to use SMTPsecure mail

Comment: you can test with $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls"; and $mail->Port       = 587;

Comment: when i use 587 it says
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:;
SMTP -> NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connected ;
Language string failed to load: tls

Comment: Your mail server reply on port 25 which is not usually used with encryption methods, try $mail->SMTPAuth   = true; and remove tls or ssl encryption, make sure username and password are true

Comment: i have got answer. Please see my answer. thanks for your time